# Connecting to IBM WebSphere MQ using .Net throws error MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I am very new to MQ and trying to configure it on my machine. The requirement is to setup MQ such that I can send/receive XML files as messages in MQ using my C#.NET code. I have installed IBM WebSphere MQ 9.0 version on my machine. As I understand so far, I will need to setup Queue Manager, Queue and Channel at the minimum to achieve this. So I have tried to set these up in my MQ. However, when I try to run my code, I get error "MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED".

Can anybody please guide me in setting up these things so that the scenario of file sharing through .NET will work? I guess the client and server both will be local on my machine in this case? There are many parameters to choose at the time of creating the Queue, Channel, etc which are confusing to me and I guess I have chosen incorrect definitions in my setup.

Here is my .Net code:

```
using IBM.WMQ;
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace MQTest
{

class MQTest
{
    public MQQueueManager ConnectMQ()
    {
        MQQueueManager queueManager;

        // Setup connection information                  
        Hashtable queueProperties = new Hashtable();
        queueProperties[MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY] = "localhost";
        queueProperties[MQC.PORT_PROPERTY] = 1414;
        queueProperties[MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY] = "QM._TEST.SVRCONN";

        try
        {
            // Attempt the connection
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QM_TEST", queueProperties);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected Successfully");
        }
        catch (MQException mexc)
        {
            // TODO: Setup other exception handling
            throw new Exception(mexc.Message
                       + " ReasonCode: " + mexc.ReasonCode
                       + mexc.StackTrace, mexc);
        }

        // For now, return the queueManager to use in reading/writing messages next
        return queueManager;
    }
 }
}
```

And here are the snapshots of my MQ setup:

**Queue Manager**
[image: Queue Manager]

**Queue**
[image]

**Channel**
[image]

**Listener**
[image]

Comment: What does the AMQERR01.LOG have in it at the time of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AladdinMQ.LOCAL.ONE

First off, it is a bad idea to use mixed case MQ objects.  You are just asking for trouble.  MQ likes to uppercase MQ objects if you don't use quotes.  So, it is best just to use uppercase MQ object names.

If your UserId is not in the mqm group then you need to give permission to your UserId to (1) access the queue manager and (2) access the queue.

i.e.

It is bet to do MQ permissions by 'Group' rather than 'UserId'.  Let's say the group needs access to queues that begin with "AladdinMQ.".  Here are setmqaut commands to setup the OAM permissions:

```
setmqaut -m QM_TEST -t qmgr -g {GROUP} +connect +inq +dsp
setmqaut -m QM_TEST -n AladdinMQ.** -t queue -g {GROUP} +allmqi +dsp
```

where {GROUP} is the name of the Group that the UserId belongs to.

Comment: Just to supplement the answer from Roger, the security permissions can be set on almost all elements in the MQ (the channel in particular).  it is possible to set a deny which will trump a authorize permission.  For example if you have permission to the queue but are denied access to the channel you can't access anything.  Also note if you are sending large files that the channel has size limits.

Comment: When I connect using my C# code, which user is used to connect to MQ? is it my machine login user?

Comment: I found out which user is being used by looking at Event Logs and then added that user to mqm group. Then it started working!

Comment: @AnilSoman adding the user to mqm is not a good way to fix the problem.  As was pointed out by Roger you should provide the user permissions to the queue(s) required, as of now your the user can fully administer the queue manager since you added it to the mqm group.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc.. i will try to remove my user from mqm group and then try to give specific access. Also when I try to access the queue remotely with other user logged in then I am getting error {2538}. Is this due to firewall settings now allowing access?