# MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED from .Net application

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I need to read messages from IBM MQ. I used the link to write the code.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/a-quick-start-with-C-Sharp-and-websphere-mq/

I have local MQ server setup on my machine.
I am getting exception MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED while trying to connect to local MQ.
I have simple console application. I don't know how I can authorize it with MQ while connecting.
My code looks like

```cs
      private static string ConnectMQ(string strQueueManagerName, string strQueueName,

string strChannelInfo)
            QueueManagerName = strQueueManagerName;
            QueueName = strQueueName;
            ChannelInfo = strChannelInfo;

            //
            char[] separator = { '/' };
            string[] ChannelParams;
            ChannelParams = ChannelInfo.Split(separator);

            channelName = ChannelParams[0];
            transportType = ChannelParams[1];
            connectionName = ChannelParams[2];
            String strReturn = "";

            try
            {
                queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName,
                channelName, connectionName);
                strReturn = "Connected Successfully";
            }

            catch (MQException exp)
            {
    }

 ConnectMQ("QM_TEST", "QM_TEST.LOCAL.ONE", "QM_TEST.SVRCONN/TCP/localhost(1421)");
        }
```

Please note I have already similar links but nothing helped.

Here is the complete error trace from AMQERR01

```
9/18/2020 19:44:34 - Process(9892.8) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:14:34.236Z)
                      CommentInsert1(Windows 10 Unknown x64 Edition, Build 18362 (MQ Windows (x64 platform) 64-bit))
                      CommentInsert2(C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ (Installation1))
                      CommentInsert3(9.2.0.0 (p920-L200710.TRIAL))
                     
AMQ6287I: IBM MQ V9.2.0.0 (p920-L200710.TRIAL).

EXPLANATION:
IBM MQ system information: 
Host Info         :- Windows 10 Unknown x64 Edition, Build 18362 (MQ Windows
(x64 platform) 64-bit) 
Installation      :- C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ (Installation1) 
Version           :- 9.2.0.0 (p920-L200710.TRIAL)
ACTION:
None. 
----- amqxeida.c : 6604 -------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:44:34 - Process(21848.20) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:14:34.235Z)
                      RemoteHost(127.0.0.1)
                      CommentInsert1(QM_TEST.SVRCONN)
                      CommentInsert2(127.0.0.1)
                      CommentInsert3(MCAUSER(shree) CLNTUSER(shree) ADDRESS(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN))
                     
AMQ9776E: Channel was blocked by userid

EXPLANATION:
The inbound channel 'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' was blocked from address '127.0.0.1'
because the active values of the channel were mapped to a userid which should
be blocked. The active values of the channel were 'MCAUSER(shree)
CLNTUSER(shree) ADDRESS(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN)'.
ACTION:
Contact the systems administrator, who should examine the channel
authentication records to ensure that the correct settings have been
configured. The ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH switch is used to control whether channel
authentication records are used. The command DISPLAY CHLAUTH can be used to
query the channel authentication records. 
----- cmqxrmsa.c : 1326 -------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:44:34 - Process(21848.20) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:14:34.236Z)
                      CommentInsert1(QM_TEST.SVRCONN)
                      CommentInsert2(21848(19112))
                      CommentInsert3(127.0.0.1)
                     
AMQ9999E: Channel 'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' to host '127.0.0.1' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 21848(19112) for channel
'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' ended abnormally. The host name is '127.0.0.1'; in some cases
the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide. 
----- amqrmrsa.c : 974 --------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:45:46 - Process(14284.38) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:15:46.955Z)
                      CommentInsert1(shree)
                      CommentInsert2(\IBM Mq\bin\Debug\IBM Mq.exe)
                      CommentInsert3(N/A)
                     
AMQ5534E: User ID 'shree' authentication failed

EXPLANATION:
The user ID and password supplied by the '\IBM Mq\bin\Debug\IBM Mq.exe' program
could not be authenticated. 
Additional information: 'N/A'.
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct user ID and password are provided by the application.
Ensure that the authentication repository is correctly configured. Look at
previous error messages for any additional information. 
----- amqzfuca.c : 4804 -------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:45:46 - Process(14284.38) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:15:46.955Z)
                      CommentInsert1(shree)
                      CommentInsert2(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
                      CommentInsert3(CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL))
                     
AMQ5542I: The failed authentication check was caused by the queue manager
CONNAUTH CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL) configuration.

EXPLANATION:
The user ID 'shree' and its password were checked because the queue manager
connection authority (CONNAUTH) configuration refers to an authentication
information (AUTHINFO) object named 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS' with
CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL). 

This message accompanies a previous error to clarify the reason for the user ID
and password check.
ACTION:
Refer to the previous error for more information. 

Ensure that a password is specified by the client application and that the
password is correct for the user ID. The authentication configuration of the
queue manager connection determines the user ID repository. For example, the
local operating system user database or an LDAP server. 

If the CHCKCLNT setting is OPTIONAL, the authentication check can be avoided by
not passing a user ID across the channel. For example, by omitting the MQCSP
structure from the client MQCONNX API call. 

To avoid the authentication check, you can amend the authentication
configuration of the queue manager connection, but you should generally not
allow unauthenticated remote access. 
----- amqzfuca.c : 4827 -------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:45:47 - Process(21848.21) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:15:47.965Z)
                      RemoteHost(127.0.0.1)
                      CommentInsert1(QM_TEST.SVRCONN)
                      CommentInsert2(127.0.0.1)
                      CommentInsert3(MCAUSER(shree) CLNTUSER(shree) ADDRESS(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN))
                     
AMQ9776E: Channel was blocked by userid

EXPLANATION:
The inbound channel 'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' was blocked from address '127.0.0.1'
because the active values of the channel were mapped to a userid which should
be blocked. The active values of the channel were 'MCAUSER(shree)
CLNTUSER(shree) ADDRESS(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN)'.
ACTION:
Contact the systems administrator, who should examine the channel
authentication records to ensure that the correct settings have been
configured. The ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH switch is used to control whether channel
authentication records are used. The command DISPLAY CHLAUTH can be used to
query the channel authentication records. 
----- cmqxrmsa.c : 1326 -------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:45:47 - Process(21848.21) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:15:47.965Z)
                      CommentInsert1(QM_TEST.SVRCONN)
                      CommentInsert2(21848(6468))
                      CommentInsert3(127.0.0.1)
                     
AMQ9999E: Channel 'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' to host '127.0.0.1' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 21848(6468) for channel
'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' ended abnormally. The host name is '127.0.0.1'; in some cases
the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide. 
----- amqrmrsa.c : 974 --------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:46:13 - Process(14284.39) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:16:13.871Z)
                      CommentInsert1(MCAUSER)
                      CommentInsert2(\IBM Mq\bin\Debug\IBM Mq.exe)
                      CommentInsert3(N/A)
                     
AMQ5534E: User ID 'MCAUSER' authentication failed

EXPLANATION:
The user ID and password supplied by the '\IBM Mq\bin\Debug\IBM Mq.exe' program
could not be authenticated. 
Additional information: 'N/A'.
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct user ID and password are provided by the application.
Ensure that the authentication repository is correctly configured. Look at
previous error messages for any additional information. 
----- amqzfuca.c : 4804 -------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:46:13 - Process(14284.39) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:16:13.871Z)
                      CommentInsert1(MCAUSER)
                      CommentInsert2(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
                      CommentInsert3(CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL))
                     
AMQ5542I: The failed authentication check was caused by the queue manager
CONNAUTH CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL) configuration.

EXPLANATION:
The user ID 'MCAUSER' and its password were checked because the queue manager
connection authority (CONNAUTH) configuration refers to an authentication
information (AUTHINFO) object named 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS' with
CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL). 

This message accompanies a previous error to clarify the reason for the user ID
and password check.
ACTION:
Refer to the previous error for more information. 

Ensure that a password is specified by the client application and that the
password is correct for the user ID. The authentication configuration of the
queue manager connection determines the user ID repository. For example, the
local operating system user database or an LDAP server. 

If the CHCKCLNT setting is OPTIONAL, the authentication check can be avoided by
not passing a user ID across the channel. For example, by omitting the MQCSP
structure from the client MQCONNX API call. 

To avoid the authentication check, you can amend the authentication
configuration of the queue manager connection, but you should generally not
allow unauthenticated remote access. 
----- amqzfuca.c : 4827 -------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:46:14 - Process(21848.22) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:16:14.882Z)
                      RemoteHost(127.0.0.1)
                      CommentInsert1(QM_TEST.SVRCONN)
                      CommentInsert2(127.0.0.1)
                      CommentInsert3(MCAUSER(shree) CLNTUSER(shree) ADDRESS(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN))
                     
AMQ9776E: Channel was blocked by userid

EXPLANATION:
The inbound channel 'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' was blocked from address '127.0.0.1'
because the active values of the channel were mapped to a userid which should
be blocked. The active values of the channel were 'MCAUSER(shree)
CLNTUSER(shree) ADDRESS(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN)'.
ACTION:
Contact the systems administrator, who should examine the channel
authentication records to ensure that the correct settings have been
configured. The ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH switch is used to control whether channel
authentication records are used. The command DISPLAY CHLAUTH can be used to
query the channel authentication records. 
----- cmqxrmsa.c : 1326 -------------------------------------------------------
9/18/2020 19:46:14 - Process(21848.22) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.0.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                      Time(2020-09-18T14:16:14.882Z)
                      CommentInsert1(QM_TEST.SVRCONN)
                      CommentInsert2(21848(15124))
                      CommentInsert3(127.0.0.1)
                     
AMQ9999E: Channel 'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' to host '127.0.0.1' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 21848(15124) for channel
'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' ended abnormally. The host name is '127.0.0.1'; in some cases
the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide. 
----- amqrmrsa.c : 974 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where can I see AMQERR01.LOG file?

Comment: The related link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518795/connecting-to-ibm-websphere-mq-using-net-throws-error-mqrc-not-authorized

Comment: It usually in the `%MQ_DATA_PATH%`. You can find version running the `dspmqver` command.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the link that Neha gave you. Also, that sample's style of connection parameters is not very useful - doesn't support SSL/TLS or security exits. You should be using a Hashtable to hold the connection information. Here's a better C# MQ sample (managed mode) that I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818863/sending-message-on-ibm-mq-hangs-on-accessqueue/49822641#49822641

Comment: Neha is the person who asked the question.

Comment: Thanks for helping Josh and Roger but I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Could you help me over screen share?

Comment: @JoshMc" Version is 9.2.0.0.. I am still not able to find AMQERR01.LOG file.

Comment: On the machine with the queue manager open a CMD prompt and run `set MQ`, you should see `MQ_DATA_PATH` set to some value.   Look in that location under `qmgrs/QM_TEST/errors`

Comment: I don't see MQ_DATA_PATH. Screenshot from my machine.C:\windows\system32>set MQ
MQSNOAUT=yes
MQ_FILE_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ
MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ
MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java
MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib
MQ_JRE_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\jre

Comment: Could paste screenshot here so pasted text from my cmd.

Comment: Then look at the data path.

Comment: Thanks for bringing me till here @JoshMc. I could find the error file but could not understand the error there. Pasting it here.

Comment: MQ9776E: Channel was blocked by userid

EXPLANATION:
The inbound channel 'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' was blocked from address '127.0.0.1'
because the active values of the channel were mapped to a userid which should
be blocked. The active values of the channel were 'MCAUSER(shree)
CLNTUSER(shree) ADDRESS(LAPTOP-2KL18VPN)'.


                     
                     
AMQ9999E: Channel 'QM_TEST.SVRCONN' to host '127.0.0.1' ended abnormally.

Comment: If you can understand the error can you help me get it resolved please?

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc- I have added the complete stack trace of the error in the question. Also Shree is a member of the Admin group.

Comment: 1. With `CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)` if you send mq a id and password it must be valid. 2. I believe even with a valid password a default CHLAUTH rule would block you as a MQADMIN user.  Try to send a valid password.

Comment: Which will be a valid ID? How do I know? I tried with UserID -"shree" and my system password . Is still not working. Also is this happening only on my local queue and will not happen on remote queue?

Comment: Was it the same four errors?

Comment: Neha Aggarwal, if you are just want it working to see if your program works, you could disable security on the queue manager for now. More details on the following link https://community.ibm.com/community/user/imwuc/viewdocument/from-the-archives-getting-going-wi?CommunityKey=b382f2ab-42f1-4932-aa8b-8786ca722d55  ....perhaps once you have completed programming, you could work with your enterprise's MQ admin to resolve any integration issues. Really depends on what you are trying to achieve....the code or resolve mq issue.

Comment: Thanks a ton people for your help JoshMc, Roger and Rohan. I could connect . Though not by cmd blockage of channel but by IBM MQ UI.

Comment: Can you explain what you needed to do to fix the issue to help future users?

Comment: I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81zxSdwm4ek link change blocked users list.

Comment: If this is resolved, could you please post an answer, with perhaps a summary of the actions suggested by the video to change the blocked users list.